# How to add Google API 8 for android versions 2.2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

i am trying to add Google API 8 for android version 2.2, andi used this  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml   link to doenload API, but i didnt get it, please help me to overcome this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the **Android SDK** from the site http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: ok if i download in sence, then what about the previous Contents? will it lost or it will be there?

Comment: If you already have the SDK installed, then just launch the "SDK Manager" and select the packages you want to install. In the list scroll down to "Android 2.2 (API 8)" and select the packages you want. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/s3avn.png